# how to merge two table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two table like this:

```
table 1
---------------
ID   Name   Fname
1    N1     FN1
2    N2     FN2
3    N3     FN3

table 2
---------------
TID     Day    Hour   ID
1       30     14     1
2       30     14     2
```

and i want show this result:

```
Result Table
---------------
ID   Name   Fname   TID     Day    Hour
1    N1     FN1     1       30     14
2    N2     FN2     2       30     14
3    N3     FN3     ---     ---    ---
```

Note: ID in Table2 is forgin key form Table1 And I Do not use join because I can't get all row in both table.

What is needed sql command to display the above table?

Thank a lot.

Comment: What query you try before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query to retrieve your desired result:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  FName, 
  (SELECT TID From Table2 WHERE ID=t1.ID) TID, 
  (SELECT [Day] From Table2 WHERE ID=t1.ID) [Day],
  (SELECT [Hour] From Table2 WHERE ID=t1.ID) [Hour]
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: I was just typing to better use left join, you beat me to it

Comment: Thank for your reply. but if i use join, i cant get all rows. [Edit question]

Comment: Thank you for your great solution my friend.

Comment: @MortezaKarimi - I'm glad that I helped you. Please upvote my answer so that other can get help as well :)

Answer (score 1):

simple left join would work

```
select 
*
from
table1 t1 
left join
table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. but if i use join, i cant get all rows. [I have edit my question]

Comment: @MortezaKarimi You clearly didn't try it.  A left outer join does exactly what you are asking for based on your data.  Since TID is a foreign key to ID, you don't need a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.Name, t1.fname, t2.TID, t2.Day, t2.Hour 
From Table` t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 
on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Rajesh.  This seems like a correct answer, but would be better if you explained why it helps.  I've also reformatted it to use markdown for the whole query.